# Is there an inline way to conditionally add an attribute in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are a number of times in Rails when I would like to be able to add an attribute to something *only if the attribute is of a particular value*.

Let me give you an example. Let's say I want to disable a button based on a particular property such as `check_if_user_can_be_added`:

```
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, disabled: (user_can_be_added?)
```

This all looks fine and well except that disabled happens to be applied in HTML regardless of what value you give it. If you give a button the attribute `disabled: false` then it will still be disabled.

### What I need

```
# if the button is disabled
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, disabled: true

# if the button is not disabled
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path
```

### The way that I can see to do it

Getting this means that you need a solution similar to the following which sets up the options hash first and then passes it in subsequently:

```
options = user_can_be_added? ? {disabled: true} : {}
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, options
```

### The way I would like to do it...

This doesn't work but trusting in Ruby's beauty I suspect there's something similar out there. This is basically what I'd like to do

```
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, ({disabled: true} if user_can_be_added?)
```

Can I do it, is there perhaps something using the splat operator that gets me there...?

Comment: Rails should take into account boolean attributes when using helpers like this – using `disabled: false` should work, leaving out the `disabled` attribute altogether.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just set nil to cause Rails to ignore the attribute:

```
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, disabled: (user_can_be_added? ? true : nil)
```

For this particular case, you can also use || like so:

```
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, disabled: (user_can_be_added? || nil)
```

Comment: Lovely - that worked a treat. I didn't know that nil caused Rails to skip the parameter. Exactly what I needed and the OR statement is a classy touch too. TY

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with rails, but inline if statements can be achieved as follows in ruby:

```
(condition ? true : false)
```

I would assume your code would look like this:

```
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, (user_can_be_added? ? disabled: true : nil)
```

This would essentially pass in `nil` in place of `disable: true` if `user_can_be_added?` resolves to false.

I'm not sure how the `link_to` function would handle that, though. I guess the reason `disabled: false` doesn't work, is the `link_to` function recieves a hash of attributes as the final parameter, which are applied to an html link. Since the `disabled` attribute in html doesn't need a value, it would just stick in `<a href="" disabled>` regardless of its value. Someone feel free to correct me though, I haven't used rails.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. The method is expecting a key-value pair and so if you pass nil it just throws an error.

Comment: Did you try using a placeholder value? eg `(user_can_be_added? ? disabled: true : tmp: "nothing")`. Super hacky though, there's probably a better way.

Comment: This was almost there but needed a tweak. @TomDavis showed that the way to skip a param is not to pass the key/value pair as nil but to pass a `key: nil` combo.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I used a Rails plugin for HTML attributes that is still available on [Github](https://github.com/stakr/html_attributes). That plugin allowed to write html tags like this:

```
content_tag(:div, :class => { :first => true, :second => false, :third => true }) { ... }
# => <div class="first third">...
```

Plugins are unsupported by current versions of Rails and plugin only worked for tag helpers, but perhaps this helps you to write a helper yourself.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to add direct HTML through a view helper without a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For many arguments, using the splat will work:

```
p "Here's 42 or nothing:", *(42 if rand > 0.42)
```

This won't work for a hash argument though, because it will convert it to an array.

I wouldn't recommend it, but you could use `to_h` (Ruby 2.0+):

```
link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, ({disabled: true} if user_can_be_added?).to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like a great place to use a helper

```
module AccountHelper 

  def link_to_create_account disabled = false
    if disabled
      link_to 'Create account', new_user_path, disabled: true
    else
      link_to 'Create account', new_user_path
    end
  end 
end
```

In your ERB it's simply `link_to_create_account(user_can_be_added?)`

Not everyone likes helpers, but they work for me.